# How to order items in ETS?

Tags: list, erlang

i insert many items in ETS like this:

```
ets:insert{{users, jim, 9}}
ets:insert{{users, ham, 3}}
ets:insert{{users, why, 2}}
ets:insert{{users, dhh, 3}}
ets:insert{{users, zend, 4}}
```

so how to get the ordered list by one number in item?

```
[
   {users, why, 2},
   {users, ham, 3},
   {users, dhh, 3},
   {users, zend, 4},
   {users, jim, 9}
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using [`lists:keysort/2`](http://erldocs.com/R14B02/stdlib/lists.html?i=0&search=lists%3akeysort#keysort/2) like so:

```
1> Result = [{users, jim, 9},
             {users, ham, 3},
             {users, why, 2},
             {users, dhh, 3},
             {users,zend, 4}].
[{users,jim,9},
 {users,ham,3},
 {users,why,2},
 {users,dhh,3},
 {users,zend,4}]
2> lists:keysort(3, Result).
[{users,why,2},
 {users,ham,3},
 {users,dhh,3},
 {users,zend,4},
 {users,jim,9}]
```